# Populate dictionary with decorator functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating an application that basically runs a bunch of tests, each of which is a separate function. I have a list of the tests/functions as a dictionary like so.

```
test = {
    "test 1": f1,
    "test 2": f2,
    "test 3": f3
}
```

I can execute the functions like this:

```
for testn, _ in test.items():
    test[testn]()
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
tests = {}

@task("test 1")
def f1():
   ...

@task("test 2")
def f1():
   ...

def run():
    for testn, _ in tests:
        tests[test]()
```

I was wondering how this would be possible.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a simple decorator to populate your function registry  `tests`:

```
tests = {}
def task(name):
   def wrapper(funct):
      tests[name] = funct
      return funct
   return wrapper

@task("test 1")
def f1():
  ...

@task("test 2")
def f2():
  ...

def run():
  for testn, _ in tests.items():
    tests[test]()
```

Now, before `run` is called, when iterating over the dictionary, it can be observed that the structure is correct:

```
print({a:b.__name__ for a, b in tests.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'test 2': 'f2', 'test 1': 'f1'}
```

Note, however, that `tests` does contain all function instances:

```
{'test 2': <function f2 at 0x10de0e5f0>, 'test 1': <function f1 at 0x10de0e578>}
```

This decorator slightly deviates from the normal decorator pattern of receiving the wrapped function, intercepting the parameters, and calling the wrapped function by merely returning the original function object passed to it. This saves the space from having to implement another wrapper to intercept the parameters and allows the registry addition to occur as soon as the function is bound to its object.

Also, note that `tests` is a dictionary, and thus attempting to iterate over it with unpacking without first calling `dict.items()` with raise a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` error.

Edit: if the functions become methods, then the solution would be:

```
class Tests:
    def __init__(self):
       self.tests = {}
    def task(self, name):
       def wrapper(f):
          self.tests[name] = f
       return wrapper

test = Tests()
@test.task('test 1')
def f1():
   pass

@test.task('test 2')
def f2():
   pass

for a, b in test.tests.items():
   pass

print({a:b.__name__ for a, b in test.tests.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'test 2': 'f2', 'test 1': 'f1'}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, how would this look if the functions were defined in a class?

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it!

Comment: @user1960118 glad to help!